# Analytic formula for $\sup_{|x| \le 1} ax + |x-b|$ as a function of $a,b \in \mathbb R$.

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Disclaimer: This should be "easy" but, I'm startled by the explosion of subcases.

---

> **Question.** What is an analytic formula for $\sup_{|x| \le 1} ax + |x-b|$ as a function of $a,b \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: Just a hunch, but it's not supposed to be $\sup_{|x| \le 1} (ax - |x - b|)$ instead? As in the Fenchel dual $f^*(a)$ of the convex function $f(x) = |x - b| + i_{[-1, 1]}(x)$?

Comment: I don't think you're doing anything wrong here. There will be a large number of cases. I would split into the major cases: $b \le -1$, $b \ge 1$, and $|b| < 1$. In the first two cases, $|x - b|$ simplifies to a linear function. Each case will have its own sub-cases to deal with, but I suspect that's just part of the exercise. In other words, don't be alarmed. :-)

Comment: At least someone else confirms there is indeed an explosion of subcases, and nothing can be done about it. Definition of a nasty problem!

Comment: I'm writing my thesis at the moment; I'm honestly pretty glad that I tackled the odd nasty problem during my undergrad. :-)

Comment: $f(x) = ax + |x-b|$ is a *convex* function of $x$, therefore the maximum is attained at the boundary of the interval: $\max_{|x| \le 1} f(x) = \max(f(-1), f(1)) = \max(|b+1|-a, |b-1|+a)$.

Comment: Indeed. Thanks for the simple but powerful remark which solves the problem in one line.

Comment: Changing the variable $t=x-b$ , one obtains By Mathematica 12.2 `Maximize[{a*(t + b) +RealAbs[t], 
   RealAbs[t + b] <= 1}, t] // Simplify`  the following `\[Piecewise] 1 (b==-1&&a==-1)||(b==1&&a==1)
2-a b==1&&a<1
-a b==-1&&a<-1
a b==1&&a>1
2+a b==-1&&a>-1
-1-a-b b<-1&&a<-1
1+a-b (-1<b<1&&a>b)||(b<-1&&a>-1)
-b b<-1&&a==-1
b b>1&&a==1
1-a+b (b>1&&a<1)||(-1<b<1&&a<=b)
-1+a+b True'  (only a part of the output is displayed).

Comment: Thanks for the input. Since ME users a not surposed to be Mathematica users, could you kindly write down what's the output in pure latex ?

Answer (score 0):

By simplifying the apparent explosion of subcases, it turns out that the problem has a nice analytic solution.

> **Lemma.** *For any $a,b \in \mathbb R$, it holds that*
> $$
> \sup_{|\theta| \le 1}a\theta +|\theta-b| = |a-b/\max(|b|,1)|+\max(|b|,1).
> $$

*Proof.*
Let $f(a,b):=\sup_{|\theta| \le 1}a\theta+|\theta-b|$.
First, suppose $b \le -1$. Then, $|\theta-b| = \theta-b$ for all $\theta \in [-1,1]$, and so $f(a,b) = \sup_{|\theta| \le 1}(a+1)\theta-b = |a+1|-b$. Next, suppose $b \ge 1$. Then $|\theta-b|=b-\theta$, and so $f(a,b) = \sup_{|\theta| \le 1}(a-1)\theta+b = |a-1|+b$. Finally, suppose $|b| < 1$. One computes
\begin{eqnarray*}
\begin{split}
f(a,b) &= \max((1+a)b-b,1+a-b,b-(a-1),b+b(a-1))\\
&=\max(ab,1+a-b,b-a+1,ab)\\
&=\max(ab,1+a-b,1-a+b)\\
&= \max(ab,|a-b|+1)\\
&= |a-b|+1,
\end{split}
\end{eqnarray*}
where the last step is because $ab \le |ab| \le |a| \le |a-b|+1$, since $|b| \le 1$. Putting things together then gives the result. $\quad\quad\Box$